# Sequential definition of continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $|f(x)| \leq M $ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ fails to exist. Show that there must be sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ in $(0,1)$ such that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ and $b_n \rightarrow 0$ while $\{f(a_n)\}$ and $\{f(b_n)\}$ both converge to different limits.

I'm having a hard time coming up with an example for this question as it seems to me that the sequences are always approaching from the right since they are within $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to suppose that $f(x)$ is defined for only $x\in (0,1)$. Let $a_n$ be any sequence converging to $0$, and $y_n=f(a_n)$. By compactness of $[-M,M]$, there exists a convergent subsequence $y_{n_k}$ converging to $y$, so $a_{n_k}$ is your first sequence. Now suppose that for *every* sequence $x_n$ converging to $0$, and *every* $\epsilon>0$, there exists only a finite number of terms of $f(x_n)$ outside of $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$. This would mean that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=y$, a contradiction. So there must be a sequence $x_n\to 0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that an infinite number of terms of $f(x_n)$ lie outside of $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$. Take $b_n$ to be the subsequence of $x_n$ consisting of those terms outside of $(y-\epsilon,y+\epsilon)$, and define $z_n=f(b_n)$. By compactness of $[-M,y-\epsilon]\cup[y+\epsilon,M]$, there exists a subsequence $z_{n_k}$ converging to $z$. Your second sequence is $b_{n_k}$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim is false. Consider $f(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$, and $f(x)=1$ if $x>0$.

Perhaps it's supposed to be a one-sided limit?

Comment: I think that perhaps we are to understand that the function is only defined on $(0,1)$, though this should be made more clear.

Comment: Yes, good point.

Comment: @AlexS yes, that's how I interpreted the question. Either way, isn't the claim still false? I've been trying to wrap my head around this question for a while.

Comment: @RedShift With this assumption, I think it is actually true. See my new answer.